# Find $\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\to 4}$$\frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}=1$, find $\lim_{x\to 4}$$f(x)$.

I plugged $4$ into the equation and i found that $f(4)-5=2$ and $f(4)=7$.

How can i find what is $\lim_{x\to 4}$$f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: you can multiply limits

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are actually almost correct.

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}=1$$

$$ \frac{\lim \limits_{x \to 4}[f(x)-5]}{\lim \limits_{x \to 4}[x-2]}=1$$

$$ \frac{\lim \limits_{x \to 4}f(x)-5}{2}=1$$

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 4}f(x)=2+5=7$$

which is almost exactly what you did.

However, notice that at no point of time did I mention $f(4)$. I cannot make such conclusion because I have no information that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: You are a life saver thank you :)